# XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set

Tags: firefox, snap

I have two issues I believe to be related:

1. The global variable XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is not set to anything.
2. There is only one user on this newly installed Ubuntu 22.04 OS. It would be expected the user number for it is 1000. This is verified by the global $UID being set to that number as expected. But the directory /run/user/1000 does not exist. The directory /run/user/ is empty.

I believe the lack of the temporary data directory at /run/user/1000 is causing firefox, and possibly other snap applications, not to run. The error I get when I attempt to run firefox is:

```
2022/07/03 16:49:54.424008 cmd_run.go:1053: WARNING: cannot start document portal: Expected portal at "/run/user/1000/doc", got "/home/stephen/.cache/doc"
/system.slice/sddm.service is not a snap cgroup
```

Where, and when, is XDG_RUNTIME_DIR supposed to be set, and /run/user/1000 created? It appears something is missing in my Ubuntu installation. What?

The value of DESKTOP_SESSION is "plasma".

The firefox command is executed in the Konsole terminal emulator which is running in Ubuntu's Desktop environment.

The syslog file can be downloaded from:

https://www.mediafire.com/file/4duykf9u2mgwa23/Target_Computer_syslog_2022-07-16.zip/file

It is a log from beginning of boot up. If there is another log that would be of greater help please let me know.

Comment: `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION`?

Comment: `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is set by your GUI. The fact that it's unset implies that you're not running under a GUI, but in a plain terminal.

Comment: It is supposed to be that the variable XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is set, and the directory /run/user/1000 created, in pam_systemd upon login. This is not happening

Answer (score 0):

To be able to run firefox I had to disable cgroup. I disabled it by following the directions in the c25 post at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1951491.
Although firefox runs, it starts up with many permission denied errors. For these I will open a new thread.