# How can I get snap applications to run in VNC session?

Tags: 22.04, snap, vnc

I have a PC running Ubuntu 22.04 that I sometimes run headless and connect to through VNC (TigerVNC server, xfce4 desktop). Since upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04, some of my applications, such as Firefox and Inkscape have changed to Snap. Normally, when I use my PC with a monitor and keyboard and mouse, all still works fine, but when connected through VNC, I can no longer open these applications. In the GUI Applications menu, they've just disappeared, and when I try to start them from the command line, I get the following error:

```
/system.slice/system-vncserver.slice/vncserver@1.service is not a snap cgroup
```

Searching online, I found a possible solution [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1767183):

```
xhost +
env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/bus firefox
```

but unfortunately I was unable to get this to work (the `xhost +` part seems to work as it should, but the command after that just gives me the same error about not being a snap cgroup). This may have to do with my `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` not being set, but I'm not sure how to solve that.

In another post, related to a similar issue, the answer (https://askubuntu.com/a/1419532/1646198) suggests to disable cgroups, citing [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1951491) discussion, but this answer also mentions "many permission denied errors", so I'm not sure whether this would be the way to go.

Does anyone know how to fix this properly?

EDIT: When I substitute `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` in the above `env` command with `/run/users/1000`, Firefox starts, but with a ton of "permission denied" errors:

```
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/gimp/2.0/help /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help none bind,ro 0 0): cannot open directory "/var/lib": permission denied
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/xubuntu-docs /usr/share/xubuntu-docs none bind,ro 0 0): cannot open directory "/var/lib": permission denied
[Parent 122148, Main Thread] WARNING: Unable to connect to ibus: Could not connect: Connection refused: 'glib warning', file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/toolkit/xre/nsSigHandlers.cpp:167

(firefox:122148): IBUS-WARNING **: 16:13:46.960: Unable to connect to ibus: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

EDIT 2: Even with monitor, keyboard and mouse attached, things don't run as they used to: when I right-click an SVG-file and select 'Open with Inkscape', the Ubuntu spinner shows up for a while, and then... nothing happens. I can now only open SVG-files directly from Inkscape (i.e. first start Inkscape, then use File - Open..., or Ctrl-O).

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: See if my post at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1492329/how-to-get-snap-applications-to-run-on-a-vnc-session works for you.

Comment: Apologies for the late response @StevePringle I just tried your modified startup script, but unfortunately it didn't work for me: I got a grey screen saying something like "Something went wrong, disabled/disconnected everything for safety". I'm afraid I just don't understand enough of what's in this script to get it to work properly for me, so I'll need to educate myself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround: Use apt versions of those apps instead of snap version.

For Firefox, follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/124466) answer. For Inkscape, run the commands

```
sudo snap remove inkscape
sudo apt install inkscape
```

EDIT: To get the most recent version of Inkscape through `apt`, the Inkscape ppa is helpful:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install inkscape
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll do that. In fact, I'm thinking of moving away from Snaps entirely, perhaps try again in a few years

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the accepted answer did work, but I want to demonstrate an alternative method using Firefox from Snap. The service was of type `forking` for the user `giulio`, but for Snap, it presents the same problem as using `sudo`. I resolved it by:

```
su giulio
# enter password
```

And then starting Firefox from that session.

Overall, by switching to the correct user before starting Firefox, you ensure that the application runs within the correct user context with the necessary permissions and access to resources, resolving the issues you encountered with starting Firefox through the systemd service.