# How to get snap applications to run on a vnc session

Tags: gnome, snap, vnc

For those of you who have wanted to run snap applications on a vnc session, I think I may have the answer for you. I installed tigervnc following the instructions in the following URL :- https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-vnc-server-ubuntu-22-04/ but modified the startup script as below:-

```
#!/bin/sh
# Start Gnome Desktop 
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
source /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh
source /etc/profile.d/xdg_dirs_desktop_session.sh
export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority
export XAUTHORITY
/usr/bin/gnome-session
x-window-manager
```

This allowed the chromium-browser snap to work for me in the vnc session desktop.

It has been tested and is working on the following architectures:-

Intel x86 running Ubuntu 22.04
AMD Ryzen running Ubuntu 22.04
Raspberry Pi 5 running Ubuntu 23.10

Let me know if it works OK for you.

Update:- also tested and working for Firefox snap

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!  I just needed to add `XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority` to my existing startup script, and everything Just Worked :)